# What happens to a running method if its object is deleted?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I'm new on StackOverflow and my first question is abot what happens to a running method, when I delete its object? Furthermore, what happens when I create a new object in the method, after I deleted the old one?

There's a small code snippet below to clarify my question. (Programming in C++11)

```
// Declaration and Definition of the class
class MyClass{
private:
    static int counterFromClass = 0;
    int counterFromObject;
public:
    MyClass() {
        counterFromObject = 0;
    }
    void ~MyClass() {}
    void doSomething();
};

// Somewhere in the code a new object of the class is generated like this:
MyClass object = new MyClass();

// Then the method is called:
object->doSomething();

// Definition of the method
void MyClass::doSomething() {
    this->counterFromObject++;
    delete object;
    MyClass object = new MyClass();
    this->counterFromClass++;
}
```

If now the method `doSomething()` is called:

1. Will the method run until its end or will it be interrupted?
2. If it runs until the end, does it belong to the deleted `object` or the new one? Both objects, the deleted and the new one, have the same name.
3. If it is interrupted, what will happen? Or is this behaviour undefined?

So far what I have expirienced, it seems that the method will run to its end and execute all commands on its way, as long as they don't affect the deleted object. E.g. manipulating a static variable like `counterFromClass` is allowed. And it seems also possible to manipulate data members of the object like `counterFromObject` inside the method, as long as they are manipulated before the delete command.

Well, the code works but I know that it's not the best programming style. So I just started to work on a better solution, but I still got curious what exactly happens and if my thougths were correct. I would be grateful for answers.

If something's wrong with the question, please let me know because I am not that familiar with asking questions on StackOverflow yet.
Thank you :)

Comment: I guess you mean to write `object = new MyClass();` instead of `MyClass object = new MyClass();`.  Also it would be better to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When you call a `object->doSomething()`, under the covers it acts like you called a global function `void MyClass_doSomething(MyClass*this)`. That may affect your understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets take this function step by step:

```
void MyClass::doSomething() {
    this->counterFromObject++;
```

This is perfectly legal. But you knew that.

```
    delete object;
```

Again, perfectly legal. However, after that, it is *your* job to ensure that no code tries to access the object behind the `object` pointer anymore. The problem is, that the `this` pointer of the currently running method contains a copy of the dead objects address; the `this` pointer is left dangling. Thus, dereferencing `this` in any way, explicitly or implicitly, will immediately yield undefined behavior.

```
    MyClass* object = new MyClass();    //I added the missing * to the type, we are not using java here.
```

This does not dereference `this`, so it's perfectly ok. Note that this does not have any effect on the currently running method. The `this` pointer is dangling, and there's no way of reassigning it.

```
    this->counterFromClass++;
```

Formally, this is undefined behavior, as you are dereferencing `this`. However, since `counterFromClass` is static, it is likely that this won't crash your process, as the compiled code won't actually access the memory behind `this`. Nevertheless, writing `this->` means you have undefined behavior, so your process may crash anyway, *or your compiler may simply throw this statement away!* Whether it does so depends only on whether the compiler is smart enough to prove that you have undefined behavior here.
(As MartinBonner has found, the standard says in section 9.4 that the object expression is evaluated even when a static member is accessed via `this->`, which means that the dangling `this` pointer is actually dereferenced according to the standard. And dereferencing a dangling pointer is undefined behavior.)

---

So, it is mostly ok to delete an object while a method is running on it, and there are uses for this (one example is a reference counted object committing suicide when it's reference count drops to zero). However, if you ever need to do this,

1. write a warning comment that you may be deleting the `this` object, and
2. make sure to return immediately afterwards.

Comment: Might be worth commenting that `MyClass::counterFromClass++;` is perfectly fine after the `delete`.  Incidentally, although I agree one should not write `this->counterFromClass` after the delete, can you quote chapter and verse to show it is UB.  I have a suspicion that it may be syntactic sugar for the safe version, and doesn't involve indirecting through `this`.

Comment: Accessing the `MyClass::counterFromClass;` static field is compiler implementation dependant if done from the `this` pointer, as this needs to check the pointer to class record stored in the object instance (as a virtual, possibly overriden field)  Don't recommend to use `this` in any case, after the instance has been `delete`d.  Undefined behaviour allows precisely this kind of things to happen.

Comment: @MartinBonner Afaik, as far as the standard concerned, it's enough to use the `->` operator on any deleted object to invoke UB. As Luis Colorado points out, compilers may optimize the access to this away if the accessed field is static, but I don't know about a line in the standard that requires that. Also consider, that `->` may be user implemented...

Comment: @cmaster: I have found chapter and verse (specifically section 9.4 (class.static) para 2).  See my comment on MSalter's answer.

Comment: @MartinBonner Good find. I've incorporated that reference into the text now. Thanks.

Comment: No compiler in existence will dereference this for access to static member: https://godbolt.org/g/gQwGwE  It wouldn't make sense. But it's still technically UB as noted elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Code and allocated space for an object are stored separately. Code is only stored once in your binary (and loaded in memory when executing the binary). Objects are created dynamically in memory, on the heap or the stack. The code of a method operates on the object's data using the `this` pointer (which is an 'invisible' argument to a method, and can be accessed by explicitly writing `this` in the method, or is used implicitly when accessing members).

Nothing will happen to the running function if you delete the object. It will continue running and execute commands. The `this` pointer will not change during execution (because, as already mentioned, it's like an argument to the function copied by value). However, if the object is deleted, it will most likely not point to anything useful. So:

- Using the `this` pointer will either give you a SEGFAULT because you access memory that doesn't belong to the application anymore
- or will access some random memory in your application, leading to undefined behavior

So to answer your questions:

1. No, it's not interrupted. It keeps executing the function.
2. It doesn't 'belong' to anything, just operates on the data pointed to by `this`. Your second new is not guaranteed to give you the same pointer value (memory address).
3. It's not interrupted, but pretty much results in undefined behavior if you keep accessing object members.

Comment: Even if you don't use the `this` pointer explicitly, references to non-static members use it implicitly. Once the object is deleted, you can only access static members.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the object invalidates the this pointer. Creating a new object a probably (but not 100%) gives you a new pointer. But in the code above, the this pointer does not magically change to the new object. You have Undefined  Behaviour.

Comment: Chapter and verse please?  Note that he doesn't use a non-static variable after the delete.

Comment: Fair point - will need to check if the unnecessary use of this poses a problem.

Comment: OK, yes it does pose a problem.  From [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) 9.4 (class.static), para 2: "A `static` member may be referred
to using the class member access syntax, in which case the object expression is evaluated."  *class member access syntax* is defined in 5.2.5, and the object expression in this case will be `*this` - boom! we have UB.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, this is undefined behavior. What happens in practice, however, is that most compiler implementations will store method instructions in the same place in memory, regardless of whether the methods are static or not, just like static member variables for a class are stored in the same place in memory. This is because method logic does not vary from instance to instance. What is stored in different memory from instance to instance is non-static member variables.

Additionally, when compiled an implicit parameter is added to the functions, which is a pointer to an instance of the class. And this is how the compiled function gets access to the member variables, through the implicit "this" pointer.

Therefore, when you delete the object in the middle of executing the function, it will continue executing until it attempts to use a non-static member variable, which was stored in memory allocated specifically for that object, that was now deallocated. At this point it may continue executing if the memory has not been reclaimed, or if you're lucky the program will crash.

Comment: `virtual` methods will also cause it to hickup

Comment: He never does use a non-static member variable after the delete, so according to you there is no UB.

Comment: Never allow any class of undefined behaviour.  Even if *all* implementations do it the same way.  Undefined behaviour is an open gate to find something implemented another way.

Comment: @MartinBonner The first sentence in my answer is the opposite of what you claim it says.

Comment: @LuisColorado Why the downvotes? This answer is not "an endorsement of UB" it's just an explanation of what happens in the posted code.

Comment: @mnistic: Yes, that sentence is correct.  I'm objecting to the second clause of the third para:  " it will continue executing until it attempts to use a non-static member variable" - and my point is that it never does attempt to use a non-static member variable.

Comment: ... but I think you are trying to describe what will happen in practise.  You need to make it very much clearer that you are *not* describing "the posted code".  You are describing how the posted code will probably behave with current compilers.

Comment: @MartinBonner Right, and according to me, it will probably not crash, at least I would be surprised if it did, because it's only accessing a static variable. It's still technically UB. Something wrong with that reasoning?

Comment: I thought I made it super clear that I was talking about what happens in "most compiler implementations". Second sentence. Suggestion on how to make it clearer, for future reference?

Comment: @mnistic, you cannot explain what happens on UB, but when you know exactly all the execution environment of the program, the compiler used, the version of that compiler, etc.  And I'm afraid you don't know that preciselly, to know what's happening in the program.  Anyway, in case you explain what _can be happening_ you'd better to notice you are speculating and not as a rule.  Your response actually doesn't provide any solution to the problem, and using the `this` pointer when the object has been deleted is not allowed.

Comment: @LuisColorado I'm not explaining what happens in UB, I'm explaining what happens in "most compiler implementations" like I said. And yes, you can know precisely that most compilers will not dereference this to access a static member, just check it out here: https://godbolt.org/g/gQwGwE. I am not speculating, I am explaining what happens in compilers based on experience. The question did not ask for a "solution to a problem", it asked for an explanation of what happens, which is exactly what I provided. Finally, the top rated answer says exactly the same thing, only broken down line by line.